# Finding URL of radio Flash stream

Tags: flash, url, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm interested in finding the true URL behind a flash player for a radio station.  I'd even be happy if tunein.com played it, but I've checked (radio station is there but doesn't play).

So I went [to the site](http://toronto.virginradio.ca/player.aspx), using both Fiddler and Chrome's Developer Tools » Network to try to sniff the URL.

The closest I was able to come to find the URL was the following:

```
http://provstatic1.amri.ca/ps/player_ckfmfm.v2.json?cb=1358934414129
```

which showed me the following code.

```
{
   "version":"2.3 beta",
   "streams":[
      {
         "mount":"cp111715.live.edgefcs.net\/live\/",
         "stream":"ckfm-aac@43556",
         "type":"audio",
         "audioCodec":"aac"
      },
      {
         "mount":"cp111715.live.edgefcs.net\/live\/",
         "stream":"ckfm-mp3@43557",
         "type":"audio",
         "audioCodec":"mp3"
      }
}
```

Which I put together as

```
http://cp111715.live.edgefcs.net/live/stream:ckfm-mp3@43557,type:audio,audioCodec:mp3
```

Perhaps my syntax is off, or it can't be done whatsoever? Can somebody attempt to help me solve this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming URLs for CKFM:

AAC stream: http://icecastsource.amri.ca/ckfm-aac (40 kbps, 44 kHz, stereo)

MP3 stream: http://icecastsource.amri.ca/ckfm-mp3 (48 kbps, 22 kHz, stereo)

Substitute the call letters to access stream URLs for other stations that use "amri.ca" streaming (occasionally need to add "AM" or "FM" to the call letters in the URL).